# Why does Key.getAlgorithm return a different result after saving and reloading the KeyStore

Tags: java, cryptography, bouncycastle, keystore, digital-certificate

I am generating a KeyPair for signing using the Elliptic Curve algorithm.  After generating the private key I store it in a KeyStore and write it to a file.  When I call Key.getAlgorithm it returns "ECDSA".  But after reloading the KeyStore from the file, Key.getAlgorithm returns "EC".  I'm wondering where this is coming from and why I am getting a different result after saving it.

Here's my code (note, for this to run you need to have the JCE unlimited strength policy files installed in your jre):

```
public static void main(String [] args) throws Exception
{
    String PROVIDER = "BC";
    String KEY_ALGORITHM = "ECDSA";
    String SIGNATURE_ALGORITHM = "SHA1WITHECDSA";
    String ALIAS = "TestAlias";
    char [] PASSWORD = "password".toCharArray();
    String KEYSTORE = "c:/test/bugs/keystore.p12";

    Security.addProvider(new BouncyCastleProvider());

    // Generate the key
    Calendar calNow = Calendar.getInstance();
    Calendar calLater = Calendar.getInstance();
    calLater.set(Calendar.YEAR, calLater.get(Calendar.YEAR) + 25);
    Date startDate = new Date(calNow.getTimeInMillis());
    Date expiryDate = new Date(calLater.getTimeInMillis());

    ECGenParameterSpec ecSpec = new ECGenParameterSpec("secp192r1");
    KeyPairGenerator g = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance(KEY_ALGORITHM, PROVIDER);
    g.initialize(ecSpec, new SecureRandom());
    KeyPair keyPair = g.generateKeyPair();

    X509V1CertificateGenerator certGen = new X509V1CertificateGenerator();
    X500Principal dnName = new X500Principal("CN=Test");
    certGen.setSerialNumber(new BigInteger(8, new SecureRandom()));
    certGen.setIssuerDN(dnName);
    certGen.setNotBefore(startDate);
    certGen.setNotAfter(expiryDate);
    certGen.setSubjectDN(dnName); // note: same as issuer
    certGen.setPublicKey(keyPair.getPublic());
    certGen.setSignatureAlgorithm(SIGNATURE_ALGORITHM);
    X509Certificate cert = certGen.generate(keyPair.getPrivate(), PROVIDER);

    // Save the keystore
    KeyStore exportStore = KeyStore.getInstance("PKCS12", PROVIDER);
    exportStore.load(null, null);
    exportStore.setKeyEntry(ALIAS, keyPair.getPrivate(), PASSWORD, new Certificate[] { cert });
    FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(KEYSTORE);
    exportStore.store(out, PASSWORD);
    out.flush();
    out.close();

    // print the info from the keystore 
    System.out.println(exportStore.getKey(ALIAS, PASSWORD).getAlgorithm());

    // Reload the keystore
    FileInputStream in = new FileInputStream(KEYSTORE);
    exportStore.load(in, PASSWORD);
    in.close();

    // print the info from the reloaded keystore 
    System.out.println(exportStore.getKey(ALIAS, PASSWORD).getAlgorithm());
}
```

Based on [this example from Bouncy Castle](http://bouncycastle.org/wiki/display/JA1/Elliptic+Curve+Key+Pair+Generation+and+Key+Factories#EllipticCurveKeyPairGenerationandKeyFactories-KeyPairGeneration), it seems correct to use "ECDSA" when generating the KeyPair.

Answer (score 1):

Oracle in its *Java Cryptography Architecture Oracle Providers Documentation for Java Platform Standard Edition* ([Java 7](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/security/SunProviders.html) / [Java 8](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/security/SunProviders.html)) requires:

> Cipher suites that use Elliptic Curve Cryptography (ECDSA, ECDH, ECDHE, ECDH_anon) require a JCE cryptographic provider that meets the following requirements:
>
> - The provider must implement ECC as defined by the classes and interfaces in the packages java.security.spec and java.security.interfaces. ***The getAlgorithm() method of elliptic curve key objects must return the string "EC".***
> - The provider must support the Signature algorithms SHA1withECDSA and NONEwithECDSA, the KeyAgreement algorithm ECDH, and a KeyPairGenerator and a KeyFactory for algorithm EC. If one of these algorithms is missing, SunJSSE will not allow EC cipher suites to be used.
> - The provider must support all the SECG curves referenced in RFC 4492 specification, section 5.1.1 (see also appendix A). In certificates, points should be encoded using the uncompressed form and curves should be encoded using the namedCurve choice, that is, using an object identifier.
>
> ***If these requirements are not met, EC cipher suites may not be negotiated correctly.***

Presumably, because your code explicitly uses a *"ECDSA" `KeyPairGenerator`*, the original key exposes that *"ECDSA"* as algorithm, but when loading the serialized representation BouncyCastle uses the *"EC"* required by Oracle.

By the way, if you set `KEY_ALGORITHM = "EC"`, you get *"EC"* in both outputs.